# In a ring $R$ with a $1_R$ with $u,v, u+v$ are units, show that $u^{-1} + v^{-1}$ is also a unit.

Tags: ring-theory

In a  non-commutative ring $R$ with a $1_R$ with $u,v, u+v$ are units, show that $u^{-1} + v^{-1}$ is also a unit.

The question seems relatively simple, but I'm having a tricky time explicitly finding the formula.

I have tried :

$(u^{-1} + v^{-1})(u-v)=1-u^{-1}v+v^{-1}u-1=-u^{-1}v+v^{-1}u$

Hints appreciated.

Comment: Everybody note: the ring is not required to be commutative.

Comment: Is this even true?  Searching for a counterexample...

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(u^{-1}+v^{-1})v(u+v)^{-1}u = (u^{-1}v + 1)(u+v)^{-1}u = u^{-1}(v+u)(u+v)^{-1}u = 1.
$$
Now, try the other direction.

Comment: Oh, wow.  Didn't see that middle move.

Comment: :D................

Comment: Nice. Saying it another way:$$u^{-1}+v^{-1}=u^{-1}(u+v)v^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$(u^{-1}+v^{-1}) u v=v+u$ implies that $(u^{-1}+v^{-1}) (u v (v+u)^{-1})=1$.   But only in the commutative case.

Comment: Distributing the first gives $u^{-1}uv + v^{-1}uv=v + v^{-1}uv$.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: In a ring with $1$, if $a$ and $c$ are units, and if $abc=1$, then $b$ is a unit.  In fact $b^{-1}=ca$.

Proof: $b(ca)=a^{-1}abca=a^{-1}1a=1$.
Showing that $(ca)b = 1$ is similar.

For your situation, look at $u(u^{-1}+v^{-1})v(u+v)^{-1}$

Then use the Lemma to conclude that $u^{-1}+v^{-1}$ is invertible.